# Java code to make connection with ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: jms, activemq-artemis

Looking for Java code to connect with ActiveMQ Artemis. Earlier I was using HornetQ for messaging, but now I need to migrate to ActiveMQ Artemis.

Comment: I have created a testbroker and started Artemis perfectly as standalone. Now i want to connect through JAVA code.

Answer (score 0):

Apache ActiveMQ Artemis ships with numerous examples.  Take a look at super-simple "queue" example for a demonstration of how to use the JMS API to connect.